# Windows authentication постоянно выдает окно авторизации

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, аутентификация

При заходе на страницу запрашивается пароль.
Она начинает дальше загружаться.
Отрисовался только вверх страницы и снова запросил пароль...
Отменил красным крестиком - отрисовался только верх страницы (что уже был отрисован)
Перегрузил страницу - вся отобразилось без запроса пароля.
Если же не отменять выдает постоянно запрос пароля.
Такая тема срабатывает при переходе по клайстерной ссылке, если переходить по серверной - пароль спрашивается только один раз в самом начале (как и должно быть)

Comment: Не понятен вопрос. Посмотрите лог-журнал "сеть" в браузере. Запросы на windows-авторизацию в журнале отображаются, сколько Auth-запросов пришлёт сервак - столько будет табличек.  Возможно это даст вам предположение куда копать. Что такое "клайстерная ссылка" - тоже не понятно, и почеме нельзя пользоваться "серверной", и что такое "серверная".

Comment: @nick_n_a а можно подробную инструкцию для IE?

Comment: Про Internet Explorer стоит забыть как про страшный сон, он официально снят с поддержки в Microsoft и по факту уже не является совместимым с интернетом. Используйте последние версии Edge, Firefox, Chrome или Safari для тестирования.

Comment: @aepot не снят под windows 8.1 and windows 10 - https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/lifecycle/faq/internet-explorer-microsoft-edge

Comment: @PashaPash ну ок, не везде, дожимаем последние соки из него теперь чтоли?)

Comment: @aepot многие компании работаю исключительно на IE

Comment: @AlrottSlimRG наверное 2 страны, где IE пользуется популярностью - это Корея (судя по моей статистике) и госструктуры РФ. Но включать поддержку для новой разработки на дырявом браузере - это ну...такое. Хотя если ваш софт не купят без этого, тогда спору нет. Но есть мнение, что софт покупают не за поддержку IE. А там где был исключительно IE, уже давно Edge. Некоторые конечно используют в Egde режим IE.

Comment: не согласен. сам работаю в крупной компании связи. не буду говорить какой

Comment: @aepot продаем свой saas на US, там 10% - IE 11. причем на 10-ке.

Comment: По теме: проверяйте, какие заголовки уходят при проблемный запросах. Есть два варианта - клиент не шлет www-authenticate, или сервер его не принимает (например, у вас ва IIS за балансировщиком, а NTLM протокол connection oriented).